# React Native close app with BackHandle not working on IOS

Tags: react-native

I try use code:

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

onPress = () => {
  BackHandler.exitApp()
}
```

- BackHandler not working on Android
- BackHandler not working on IOS ?

Answer (score 3):

`BackHandler` is specifically for Android and tvOS functions and is not applicable in iOS apps. It is meant to detect hardware back button presses and iOS devices don't have a hardware back button.

It looks like you are trying to close the app on a button press, but this is not a very common pattern for iOS apps so maybe reconsider if you need it in your app. However, if you need this functionality, you can use [react-native-exit-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app) to programmatically exit the application.

Answer (score -6):

For Android, Use BackAndroid to exit the App

```
import React, {
    BackAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

BackAndroid.exitApp();
```

Comment: Deprecated. Use BackHandler instead.